# What is this nut called and can it be removed and reused/replaced?

Tags: repair, tools, hardware, hand-tools, blinds

Can anyone tell me what this nut is called and how to remove it in a way I can return the mechanism to normal working order? Also, what kind of special tools will I need?

The first photo is of the outside end-cap of a set of vertical blinds. The gear on the other side, not shown in the first picture, connects into a long shaft used to rotate the row of blinds to vary the amount of light coming through a glass door.

I'm actually trying to replace a broken axle that held some pulleys for the draw strings purposed to slide all the blinds in one direction or another. However, the pulley axle was located in this end-cap assembly. In order to get to their area, I need to remove this end, it looks like, and the only thing barring removal seems to be this weird looking nut.

Second photo is a view from the other side which shows how the gear couples to the shaft. *Maybe there is a different way to uncouple and remove the end cap?*

[image: special nut at the end of a vertical blinds gear]

[image: vertical blind gear coupling]

Comment: it is hard to tell from the picture but a lot of blinds that the metal nut and the whole white piece would be the roller mechanism.  This mechanism can just be pulled away from the bar.  Is there no way to remove the mechanism without removing the nut?  The 2nd picture looks like you could remove the whole white end plastic, then remove the roller mechanism from the white end piece assembly.

Comment: The rod usually has a groove that makes it hard to get these off.

Comment: Just to be clear, although they are sometimes referred to as a `push nut`, it's not truly a "nut" since it has no internal threads, and the piece it attaches to has no external threads. It's more along the lines of a `retaining clip` and sometimes called a `Shaft Retainer`. As @george-anderson mentions, they are commonly referred to as `push-on fasteners`. One brand of the item is `Starlock® push-on fasteners`. A similar item that is designed for use on a threaded shaft is called a `PalNut®`.

Answer (score 12):

I wish comments would allow pictures, but what you have is something generically called a "push on fastener"   I have to disagree with jsotola, I consider them "barely reusable", they often break when when removing, esp. if old.   I wouldn't count on being able to re-use it.

I attached a pic of something what I think is close to what you have.

[image: press fastener]

Comment: The standard way to remove these is actually to simply break them off and replace them with new.  They're designed for fast, cheap assembly of things that are not designed to be repaired.  Agreed with "barely reusable".

Comment: FYI for the future, you could upload an image in the editor for answering, then copy the generated image link into a comment, then discard the answer.

Comment: This is often called a "push nut" in the US.

Comment: Another solution is to do away with this item and use epoxy to secure the chain pulley to the shaft.  Even hot glue might be fine because there is very limited sideways force - the chain pulley is splined onto the shaft so transmit drive to the curtain.

Answer (score 5):

Called things like locking clip ...

But I get them off by preloading them with one small screwdriver then tweaking each of the locking tabs in turn with a second small screwdriver so it moves off.

Answer (score 2):

The manufactures technical term is "[Internal Tooth Star Lock Washers](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07S853158)"

The teeth maintain a spring-type force to keep the nut in place while resisting any chance to rotate.

It is best practice that if they are removed to replace with a new one.